# Some services are not able to be constructed === When I tend to build my API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have models:

```
  public class Employees
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string First_name { get; set; }
        public string Last_name { get; set; }
        public string User_name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone_number { get; set; }
        public string Mobile_number { get; set; }
        public bool Active_is { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class HasRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Employees_id { get; set; }
        public int Role_id { get; set; }
        public TimeOnly Time_from { get; set; }
        public TimeOnly Time_to { get; set; }
        public bool Active_is { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Role_name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have IRepository:

```
  public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        public Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get_all_Information();
        public Task<TEntity> Get_by_Id(int id);
    }
```

and Implementation:

```
 public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected IDbConnection _connection;
        protected IDbTransaction _transaction;
        protected string title_table;

        public RepositoryBase(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction, string titleTable)
        {
            _connection = connection;
            _transaction = transaction;
            title_table = titleTable;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get_all_Information()
        {
            var query = $"Select * From {title_table}";
            return await _connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>(query, transaction: _transaction);
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> Get_by_Id(int id)
        {
            string query = $"Select * From {title_table} Where Id = @id";
            var result =
                await _connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TEntity>(query, param: new { id }, transaction: _transaction);

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"{title_table} with id [{id}] could not be found.");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Employee Repository:

```
  public class EmployeesRepository : RepositoryBase<Employees>, IEmployeesRepository
    {
        public EmployeesRepository(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction) : base(connection, transaction, "Employees")
        {
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employees>> Get_all_activity_Employees()
        {
            string query = "Select * From [dbo].Employees Where Active_is = 1";
            IEnumerable<Employees> result = await _connection.QueryAsync<Employees>(query, transaction: _transaction);
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employees>> Get_all_Employees_By_Specialization(string specialization)
        {
            string query = "Select a.First_name, a.Last_name, b.Role_name " +
                           "From Employees a, Role b, Has_Role c " +
                           $"Where c.Employees_id = a.Id and c.Role_id = b.Id and b.Role_name = {specialization}";

            IEnumerable<Employees> result = await _connection.QueryAsync<Employees>(query, transaction: _transaction);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I add Scoped to DI

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(s =>
{
    s.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Swagger Example-Dapper-Migration API",
        Description = "Base Swagger Description"
    });

    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});

builder.Services.AddScoped((s) => new SqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbTransaction>(s =>
{
    SqlConnection connection = s.GetRequiredService<SqlConnection>();
    connection.Open();
    return connection.BeginTransaction();
});

// Dependency Injections 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>()
    .AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IEmployeesRepository, EmployeesRepository>();


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger API Version");
        s.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and I have the Problem:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Dapper_Data_Access_Layer.Repository.Contracts.Interfaces.IEmployeesRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Dapper_Data_Access_Layer.Repository.Contracts.EmployeesRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Data.IDbConnection' while attempting to activate 'Dapper_Data_Access_Layer.Repository.Contracts.EmployeesRepository'.)'

I create the RoleRepository and HasRoleRepositroy, but I have the same problem. I only start learning it and maybe my mistake is very simple, but I will be very grateful for the help

Comment: Are any queries working?  I can't tell from error if the connection is completing (connection string or credentials are wrong), or the mapping between the c# classes and the database is failing.  You may need to refresh the mapping if any of the columns in the database or c# classes have changed.

Comment: https://github.com/TkachYevhenii2303/Example-Dapper-API-Migration This is my Repository, can you check it?

Comment: Other queries are working! and mapping between classes work good

Comment: If other queries are working than the connection is completing.  Did you run migration and did it pass?  migration takes the c# dbContext classes and updates the database.  If the database and classes are not consistent than you will get errors.  If migration passes and you still get errors than you have to debug the controller at the server.  The error message is not giving enough info to find issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception message says that Repository cannot find the registered `IDbConnection` implementation. The possible reason is that built-in IoC didn't map your `SqlConnection` to the `IDbConnection`.

> builder.Services.AddScoped((s) => new SqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));

Therefore, try to register it explicitly:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(s => new SqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));
```

Make sure it is registered by checking `IServicesCollection`.

UPD:

I downloaded your project and rechecked the code. The answer seems to be right - I tried to register `IDbConnection` explicitly and it has been built for `EmployeesRepository`, however the similar issue appeared for `DepartmentRepository` as you wait for `SqlConnection` there.

The solutions are:

1 - Use the same parameter everywhere (`SqlConnection` or `IDbConnection`) for injections

**OR**

2 - Register both `SqlConnection` and `IDbConnection` (which is not good approach)

Also keep in mind, that if you choose to use `IDbConnection` only, it might fail in runtime over here:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbTransaction>(s =>
{
    // line below will fail as there is no SqlConnection service in the Collection
    // Use IDbConnection here as well
    SqlConnection connection = s.GetRequiredService<SqlConnection>();
    connection.Open();
    return connection.BeginTransaction();
});
```

Comment: I change the configuration but have the same problem.

Comment: @TkachYevhenii review my updated answer please. Are you sure the exception is the same? For me it was caught in another place - `DepartmentRepository`, as there is `SqlConnection` injected, that was replaced by `IDbConnection`